# Pattern matching perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to search any file matching this condition `*_abc_*.txt` in a folder. I knew my regex usage is wrong but somehow I do not know how to fix. Thanks in advance.

```
chdir $dir;
opendir my $dh, $dir or die "can't open directory:$!";
while (my $entry = readdir $dh){

  if($entry !~ m{\ *?_abc_*?[.]txt\z}x){

  <do_something>

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
opendir my $dh, $dir or die "can't open directory:$!";
while (my $entry = readdir $dh){
  if($entry !~ m{(.*?)\_abc\_(.*?)\.txt$}i){
    print $entry,"\n";
  }
}
```

Try the above. It will workout.

Comment: You should not have replaced `$` with `\z`. `\z` is the correct atom to use.

Comment: Note that the `_` don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Thank you. I tried on this and change $ to \z. Works well.

Answer (score 4):

`*` doesn't mean the same thing in regex as it does in shell globs. They're similar, but not the same.

`*` means zero or more occurrences of the preceding match. So `\ *` matches zero or more spaces. `_*` matches zero or more underscores. So a `*` in glob, would be functionally equivalent to `.*` in a regex.

Whilst I can point you how to fix your regex, I think a better answer would be to use `glob` in the first place:

```
foreach my $filepath ( glob ( "$dir/*_abc_*.txt" ) ) {
  # do something
}
```

And not try and regex match in the first place.

Comment: Nit: Regex `.*` is only equivalent to glob `*` when `/s` is used.

Comment: Code injection bug. `"$dir/*_abc_*.txt"` should be `"\Q$dir\E/*_abc_*.txt"`. Your version will fail for paths containing spaces and other characters, a significant portion of the (absolute) paths on my machine.